# append a string to column that meets a creteria

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql Varchar column called "link" containing urls. for example:

**"index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=35"**

i would like to add a zero character to the id's for all links that have the string 
**"index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id="** in them

and also meet the criteria of having the value **"top-menu"** in the **"menutype"** column.

the result will be this:
**"index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=350"**

i have this statement

> UPDATE table SET `link` = CONCAT_WS('','0','link') WHERE
>   menutype='top-menu'

but how to append it to only link values that have the string **"index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id="** in them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring_index` to see if there is something after `id`

```
mysql> select substring_index('index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=','id=',-1);
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index('index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=','id=',-1) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substring_index('index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=0','id=',-1);
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index('index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=0','id=',-1) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So in the update statement you may have the condition as

```
WHERE menutype='top-menu'
and
substring_index(link,'id=',-1) = ''
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt test this since Ben's answer already did the job, thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a link-field which contains "index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=" also always starts with that value this statement should do the trick:

```
UPDATE table 
SET link = CONCAT_WS('','0','link') 
WHERE menutype='top-menu' 
AND link LIKE 'index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=%'
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben Pi your direction was good but it needed some fixing, this the correct way:


UPDATE jos_menu SET link = CONCAT(link,'0') WHERE menutype='top-menu' AND link LIKE 'index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=%'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ben Pi i managed to get the right way to do it

```
UPDATE jos_menu SET link = CONCAT(link,'0') WHERE menutype='top-menu' AND link LIKE 'index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=%'
```